# Attempting to power a 120 V, 0.4 A cartridge heater with a 120 V, 10 A variac

Tags: power-supply, current, ac, heater, autotransformer

I have a small AC cartridge heater that has a max. input of 120 V and 0.4 A. I would like give full power to this heater (~50 W).

I am trying to power the heater with a variable auto-transformer that has a 120 V input, 140 V output and a constant current load of 10 A. More information on the variac [here](https://www.newark.com/staco-energy-products/3pn1010b/variable-transformer/dp/83F2006).

Can I use this for this scenario or not? I don't quite understand the constant current load part. If I can't, what sort of power supply or heater controller would you suggest for something with such a small current load like this?

Comment: It's fine. 10A is its max current rating, it'll happily supply less. Ridiculously expensive for hte job though.

Comment: Please show a photo and/or schematic diagram of how this is all connected, including any connections inside the Variac if that was altered.

Comment: It is connected as directly as possible. Literally a 2 prong plug with stripped wires connected directly to heater wires using lever wire connector nuts. As far as I know, nothing about the variac has been altered.

Comment: A variac normally has 4 terminals.  Make sure you're using the right ones.

Answer (score 2):

That Variac should be fine - your heater element will only draw the current it requires.

I would take the "10 Amp Constant Current" to mean that it can supply 10 Amps indefinitely without damage (and may be able to supply a little more short-term).

Comment: Ok, well i haven't been able to get it to actually supply power to my heaters at all. Even after trying multiple different heaters. When i just use a multi-meter to make sure its working, the multi-meter reads ~50 volts and not 140V at 100%, but when i connect the heater, i read no voltage at all. Not sure how to proceed.

Comment: @Lukas It would be prudent to check the fuse on the variac... and be sure the meter is set to measure AC volts, and check ITS fuse as well.

Comment: @Lukas  You might have to hit the heater with a higher voltage before the coils will start to warm up.   If these work like an incandescent light bulb (and I think they do), they're not going to present any significant resistance until they get hot.  When things get hot, their resistance (usually) goes up.  If you don't hit it hard enough at the start, it may never start getting hot.   I dunno if I'm explaining that well.   It's sorta like saying you gotta "ignite" the heater wire first, then maybe you can back the voltage down.

Comment: @Lukas It sounds like the Variac is defective or damaged, or you have an incorrect connection. The heater resistance will not change significantly over normal operating voltages from 0 to 140 VAC.

Comment: @Lukas   Try testing the variac using a simple table lamp and incandescent bulb. If the problem isn't the fuse then perhaps the internal windings or wiper contact is burned or worn out. Even the output receptacle could be worn or broken internally if the variac has seen years of heavy use. Any chance you picked up the variac second hand at a bargain price?